# karabiner - remap alt tab to different keys

Tags: macos, alt-tab, karabiner

Is it possible to remap `left_option + tab` to alt-tab and `left_option + shift + tab` for reverse alt-tab?

Configuration below has problems with changing the direction of the selection, for example switching from alt-tab to alt-shift-tab first closes the alt-tab and opens another one.

Is it possible to catch all events while `left_option` is held down and check whether `tab` is pressed in combination with the `shift`?

```
   {
      "type": "basic",
      "from": {
        "key_code": "tab",
        "modifiers": {
          "mandatory": ["left_option"],
          "optional": ["caps_lock"]
        }
      },
      "to": [
        {
          "key_code": "tab",
          "modifiers": ["left_command"]
        }
      ]
  },
  {
      "type": "basic",
      "from": {
        "key_code": "tab",
        "modifiers": {
          "mandatory": ["left_option", "left_shift"],
          "optional": ["caps_lock"]
        }
      },
      "to": [
        {
          "key_code": "tab",
          "modifiers": ["left_command", "left_shift"]
        }
      ]
  },
```